# Defining WTFoms form raises TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I'm trying to define a simple form with Flask-WTF.  I get `TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases`.  Why am I getting this error?

```
from flask_wtf import form

class RegisterForm(form):
    pass
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 5, in <module>
    from flask_init import app
  File "/Users/sapp/Desktop/ude/flask_init/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from author import views
  File "/Users/sapp/Desktop/ude/flask_init/author/views.py", line 3, in     <module>
    from form import RegisterForm
   File "/Users/sapp/Desktop/ude/flask_init/author/form.py", line 5, in <module>
    class RegisterForm(form):
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You imported the module `form` and passed that as a base class of your `RegisterForm`.  A module is not a valid base class.  You were looking for `form.Form`, the class `Form` in that module.

```
from flask_wtf.form import Form

class RegisterForm(Form):
    pass
```